# Calculate every value in a vector within a function

Tags: r, function, vector

I made a function which will calculate if a certain year is a leapyear which looks like this:

```
isLeapday<-function(x) {
     if (as.numeric(x)%%100==0 & as.numeric(x)%%400==0 | as.numeric(x)%%4==0 &      as.numeric(x)%%100!=0) return (TRUE) 
     else return (FALSE)
}


isLeapday(x)
```

I get the error message

> "In if (as.numeric(x)%%100 == 0 & as.numeric(x)%%400 == 0 | as.numeric(x)%%4 ==  :
>   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

Basically only the first value is calculated, how do I make it so that it counts every value within the vector and if possible, returns a logical vector?

Comment: Have you seen the `leap.year` function in `chron`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
isLeapday<-function(x) {
  x %% 100 == 0 & x %% 400 == 0 | x %% 4 == 0 & x %% 100 != 0
}

years <- 2004:2013

isLeapday(years)

# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Or as mnel mentioned:

```
library("chron")
leap.year(years)

 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

For the code of `leap.year{chron}`:

```
library("chron") 
edit(leap.year)

function (y) 
{
    if (inherits(y, "dates")) 
        y <- month.day.year(as.numeric(y), origin. = origin(y))$year
    y%%4 == 0 & (y%%100 != 0 | y%%400 == 0)
}
```

Comment: Personal preference is to avoid ifelse(), I find it doesn't work intuitively. He could have just used vapply(x,isLeapday)

Comment: I think it's easy to understand when written as `(year %% 4 == 0) & ((year %% 100 != 0) | (year %% 400 == 0))`